# How can we create a blank Pdf using pypdf2?

Tags: python, pdf, python-3.8, pypdf, python-pdfreader

```
import PyPDF2
writer = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()
writer.addBlankPage(219, 297)
with open (r"C:\\Users\\Aditya\\.spyder-py3\\scripting in python\\sample pdf with python\\mergedpdf.pdf","wb") as file:
    writer.write(file)
    file.close()
```

unable to create the pdf using this.

Comment: You don't need to close the file when you are using context managers

Comment: the code is working fine in my system

Comment: Did you receive any error when you try to run such code?

Comment: I think your path is wrong. You're using `r` with double slashes. Take out the `r`.